# Git only commit several files

Tags: linux, git

Im using Git on Linux. My problem is, that I have some LaTex-Files that should be comitted, but not all. I only want to commit the .tex -Files, so no crap is commited.

But when other files are in the direktory, wich are unversioned I get an error: I should add the unversioned files before I commit the changed files.

Comment: Could you show the complete terminal output and the commands you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Jonathan Brinks answer: [here](https://gist.github.com/kogakure/149016) you have a sample .gitignore to add into your latex folder.

All files with the shown endings will be ignored when it comes to adding (e.g. add --all) and commiting.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the [stage](http://githowto.com/staging_changes) is something to look more into. In Git, you use the stage to "build-up" commits.

So, the general process is like this:

```
git add path/to/file1
git add path/to/file2
git commit -m "changed file1 and file2"
```

If you have a bunch of LaText files and only want some of them to be committed, then only "add" those particular files.

If some of those LaText files are *never* meant to be committed, add them to your [.gitignore file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: Thx for help, it functioned. i use
git commit /path.../file.tex -m 'commit message'
and then git push. then it doesn't show me errors
gitignore is a nice alternative